# I want to set the permissions of the target folder to 777

Tags: permissions, mount

I am using ubuntu 18.04.

I will mount SD, USB to a specific folder.

I want 777 permissions for that mounted folder.
However, after mounting, the permissions will be reset.

I want to know how to set permissions of mounted folder to 777.

```
    root@mount-test:/work/test# pwd
    /work/test
    root@mount-test:/work/test# 
    root@mount-test:/work/test# whoami
    root
    root@mount-test:/work/test# 
    root@mount-test:/work/test# ls
    root@mount-test:/work/test# ls -al
    Total 8
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096  6월 22 13:43 .
    drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096  6월 22 13:42 ..
    root@mount-test:/work/test# 
    root@mount-test:/work/test# mkdir mnt
    root@mount-test:/work/test# ls -al
    Total 12
    drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  6월 22 13:43 .
    drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096  6월 22 13:42 ..
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096  6월 22 13:43 mnt
    root@mount-test:/work/test# 
    root@mount-test:/work/test# chmod 777 mnt
    root@mount-test:/work/test# ls -al
    Total 12
    drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  6월 22 13:43 .
    drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096  6월 22 13:42 ..
    drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096  6월 22 13:43 mnt
    root@mount-test:/work/test# 
    root@mount-test:/work/test# 
    root@mount-test:/work/test# ls /dev/sdb*
    /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1
    root@mount-test:/work/test# 
    root@mount-test:/work/test# mount /dev/sdb1 mnt
    root@mount-test:/work/test# ls -al
    Total 24
    drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096  6월 22 13:43 .
    drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096  6월 22 13:42 ..
    drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 16384  1월  1  1970 mnt
    root@mount-test:/work/test#
```

Comment: 777  - ? you nearly never want this :) also write your mount in fstab file, but don't forget to put some small timeout so the system don't hang when it's not mounted

Comment: 1. You do not need 777. 2. Change permissions AFTER mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the `umask` option of the `mount` command.

```
    root@mount-test:/work/test# ls -al
    Total 8
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096  6월 22 16:20 .
    drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096  6월 22 13:42 ..
    root@mount-test:/work/test# 
    root@mount-test:/work/test# mkdir mnt
    root@mount-test:/work/test# 
    root@mount-test:/work/test# mount -o umask=0000 /dev/sdb1 mnt
    lroot@mount-test:/work/test# ls -al
    Total 24
    drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096  6월 22 16:20 .
    drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096  6월 22 13:42 ..
    drwxrwxrwx 12 root root 16384  1월  1  1970 mnt
    root@mount-test:/work/test#
```